# What is the purpose of boiler damper?

Tags: boiler, ventilation

Gas hydronic boilers usually have a mechanically controlled damper along the way of its ventilation stack, typically near the appliance itself, for proximity of electrical connection. Is their only purpose to close the vent when the burner is not in function or does it open and close during function for various reasons? Is the only effect of not having it less energy efficiency or do they play a (vital) role in the function of pushing fumes out to the stack?

[image]

Comment: You might want to do some thorough research and read about the boilers and how they work.

Comment: Mainly to keep maximum heat while letting maximum fumes/exhaust out.  When it gets hot it does need as great of an opening letting heat out.

Comment: @crip659, you seem to have a lot of good info.  You should use the answer box more often than the comments.  Just add a few more lines and make it an answer.  having a short, correct answer is better than having a good comment and an "unanswered" question.  Plus, you get more internet points!

Comment: @JPhi1618  Half the time just guessing and waiting to see how wrong the experts say I am.  This looks like same function as on a wood stove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an article you might like: https://www.phcppros.com/articles/149-vent-dampers, and as it states at the beginning: *The views represented in the column are the author's and not the publisher's.*

> What is the purpose of a vent damper? The idea is to retain the heat in the block during the boiler off cycle and to prevent the chimney from drafting air through the boiler and up the chimney. This raises the AFUE a point or two, and ideally saves the end user in fuel usage and operating cost.

The author goes on to say that the damper isn't that useful and causes more harm than good when it eventually breaks, but that is all editorializing.  The main point is that the damper just stops airflow through the unit when it's not burning to try and hold on to some residual heat for longer.  If you know what the damper is, and how to troubleshoot and replace it on your own, most of the negatives are cancelled out (expensive repairs, stranded without heat, etc).

Comment: So if you don't have it (functional), it just lets air in during off cycle but doesn't break any critical function.

Comment: @amphibient, right, it's not emissions related to stop gas from entering the room or something like that.  It's just a draft stopper.  If it works, or you can get a replacement motor for cheap, I would install it.  No sense in losing heat if you already have a way to stop it, but if its more expensive...